# Set action in controller rather than router

Tags: php, routes, silverstripe

I have a catch call controller because of some custom database driven URLs

```
'$URLSegment/$Name/$Action/$ID': 'BaseController'
```

The `BaseController` overrides `ModelAsController` and routes it if possible, if not hands over to the parent `getNestedController` to be handled by the CMS.

However, now the action is the third URL segment, and the CMS doesn't look at the name part. (I'm assuming it will look at the `$ID` part for the third part. So now I have URLs like:

```
parent/whateverishereisignored/child
```

I can get the action in the and rearrange the URL to before handing over to the CMS but all my attempts to try and set it have failed. Can I set the Action and ID of the request manually?

I'm on Silverstripe 3